# How do I tell org mode what comment syntax to use?

Tags: emacs, raku

I am currently trying to set up a Raku script in Org Mode. However, the Raku major mode does not define a comment syntax. Is there a way to tell the Org Mode comment header argument what comment syntax to use as a header argument?

For example, this code block

```
* This should be a comment
#+BEGIN_SRC raku :comments org
lorem ipsum
#+END_SRC
```

when compiled prompts me about not having a defined comment syntax.
For reference, in the Raku Major mode (the official one), comments are properly highlighted like this

```
# This is a comment
constant Str this = "is not.";
```

Comment: Why do you assume that the major mode does not define a comment syntax? I don't know if there are multiple raku major-mode implementations but at least [this one](https://github.com/Raku/raku-mode) seems to highlight comments just fine.

Comment: The problem is with the :comments header-argument, which for some reason is broken on the largest Raku major mode.

Comment: Could you give an example that shows the problem you describe?

Comment: ... and what the "largest" Raku major mode is?

Comment: @dolandh Example added to origional question

Comment: @NickD The official one

Comment: If you mean the one distributed with emacs, I checked my emacs sources: there is no `*raku*` anything in there. So which one is the "official" one? Actually, that does not matter: what matters is which one are you using?

Comment: I meant the one made by the Raku developers as a part of the Raku project (https://github.com/Raku/raku-mode )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can figure out by reading the Org Mode documentation, the `:comments` header argument is only meaningful when also using the `:tangle` header argument. It relates to how contextual comments get added to the tangled code.

https://orgmode.org/manual/Extracting-Source-Code.html#Extracting-Source-Code

The following code block shows three of the comment insertion methods that are available:

```
* Tangled Header Comment
#+begin_src raku :results output :comments org :tangle yes :shebang #!/usr/bin/env raku
  say 'hi';
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:

* Link Comments
#+begin_src raku :results output :comments link :tangle yes :shebang #!/usr/bin/env raku
  say 'hello';
#+end_src

* Both Link and Org Comments
#+begin_src raku :results output :comments both :tangle yes :shebang #!/usr/bin/env raku
  say 'hello';
#+end_src
```

After tangling (with `Ctrl-c Ctrl-v t`) the resulting .raku file looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env raku
# Tangled Header Comment

say 'hi';

# [[file:~/git/play.org::*Link Comments][Link Comments:1]]
say 'hello';
# Link Comments:1 ends here

# Both Link and Org Comments

# [[file:~/git/play.org::*Both Link and Org Comments][Both Link and Org Comments:1]]
say 'hello';
# Both Link and Org Comments:1 ends here
```

I don't think this behaviour has anything to do with **raku-mode** which I installed from Melpa. It does require a Raku backend for Org Babel. I am using ob-raku.el which I think I got from here:

https://github.com/tmtvl/ob-raku

Comment: It may be a missing org-babel backend, as I already have tangling set up (I am using org for literate config files in this case). Thanks!